# Predict outputs based on a variable subset of inputs

Tags: prediction, features, training-datasets, feature-selection, feature-engineering

To simplify this: I have 5 columns in my dataset -> A, B, C, D and E. I want the neural network to predict the rest of the outputs based on a subset of inputs.

For example:

Case #1
Inputs -> (A) | Outputs -> (B, C, D, E)

Case #2
Inputs -> (E) | Outputs -> A, B, C, D

Case #2
Inputs -> (A, C) | Outputs -> (B, D, E)

Case #3
Inputs -> (B, D, E) | Outputs -> (A, C)

Ensemble models do not scale well as I would have to train a model with all the permutations and combinations (in this case 5! = 120 models).

What I have tried:

MICE Imputation: To fill in the missing data for the features based on the given inputs. Not sure this is a good approach.

Autoencoder: To mask and encode the features but with the variable nature of inputs, I would require to eventually resort to permutations and combinations as I actually have ~200 features / variables in my dataset.

Multiple models: With ~200 features / variables (not sure about whether to call them variables or features) in my dataset, having to create all the possible permutations and combinations is not possible. Ideally, I would like a single model to have the shape of the input number of features and the shape of the output to be the rest of the variables.

Thank you for the help!